# Roots of polynomials, negative real part

Tags: polynomials, roots, stability-theory

I'm studying for an engineering exam, but I haven't understood a mathematical concept..

Let's consider 
$\Delta(s)=a_ns^n+a_{n-1}s^{n-1}+...+a_0$. We say that we have stability if all the roots of $\Delta(s)$ have negative real part.

Now let's consider a set of polynomials that correspond to another given set P.
[image]

and switch to the coefficient space, suppose we have a convex domain like this one:

[$\underline{a_0},\bar{a_0}$]+[$\underline{a_1},\bar{a_1}$]$s+$[$\underline{a_2},\bar{a_2}$]$s^2$
[image]

My problem now is: 
'If you want to know if any polynomial belonging to the box is stable, you have to check the stability of only 4 polynomials, following these steps (starting from 0 degree)':
[image]

They are related to the verteces.
Well, I can't understand. Any vertex is defined by 3 parameters, why in the picture there are 6 bars?

Maybe its related to some Vladimir Kharitonov's works.. I have googled something but I haven't found anything, and nothing is written in my book... many thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe it's not talking about the degree-3 case specifically? Maybe it means that for arbitrary $n$, check $(\underline{a_0}, \underline{a_1}, \overline{a_2}, \dots)$, $(\underline{a_0}, \overline{a_1}, \overline{a_2}, \dots)$, etc.